# SQL Server stored procedure expects parameter: error while calling from code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have written this stored procedure that accepts the `clientId` as parameter. As you can see in the SQL Server trace, I have passed the client id while calling from .NET, but still its showing the error that `clientId` parameter is not supplied. What am I doing wrong ?

Stored procedure:

[image]

SQL Server trace when calling from .NET:

[image]

I'm still getting the error:

> Procedure or function 'USP_LoadPerformaceTemplate' expects parameter '@clientId', which was not supplied.

Comment: Does that error show up in your trace? It should - so perhaps you are not looking at the source of the problem. The most likely explanation is a fault in your application code - which you should post. And please avoid using images - something a person with your rep should know.

Comment: The call to the SP *is* missing the parameter. The call to `sp_executesql` passes it, but that statement it runs does nothing with said parameter; it just runs the SQL `dbo.USP_LoadPerformaceTemplate`. we need the application code here.

Answer (score 1):

In your C# code (which you haven't shown us), you have not set `CommandType`

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
// or
using (var command = new ... { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
```

So what is happening is that the SQL is being interpreted as a direct query batch:

```sql
[dbo].[USP_LoadPerformaceTemplate]
```

The word `EXEC` is not needed. So it is trying to execute it without the parameter.

But when `CommandType.StoredProcedure` is specified, it is sent as an RPC command to call the stored procedure.